# Set attribute to all child elements via xsl:choose

Tags: xml, xslt

assuming I got following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<MyCarShop>
    <Car gender="Boy">
        <Door>Lamborghini</Door>
        <Key>Skull</Key>
    </Car>
    <Car gender="Girl">
        <Door>Normal</Door>
        <Key>Princess</Key>
    </Car>
</MyCarShop>
```

I want to perform a transformation so the xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<MyCarShop>
    <Car gender="Boy">
        <Door color="blue">Lamborghini</Door>
        <Key color="blue">Skull</Key>
    </Car>
    <Car gender="Girl">
        <Door color="red">Normal</Door>
        <Key color="red">Princess</Key>
    </Car>
</MyCarShop>
```

So I want to add a color attribut to each subelement of Car depending on the gender information.

I came up with this XSLT but it doesnt work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!--<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>-->

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="MyCarShop">
      <xsl:attribute name="version">1.0</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Car">
    <xsl:element name="Car">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Door">
    <xsl:element name="Door">
          <xsl:attribute name="ViewSideIndicator">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="gender = 'Boy' ">Front</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="gender = 'Girl ">Front</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Key">
    <xsl:element name="Key">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anybody know what might be wrong ?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed value in test to ../@gender and now this template adds color attribute to the 'Door' node depending on value of 'gender' attribute of the Car. 
.. means 'get parent node'. 
@ means 'get value of the attribute'.

```
<xsl:template match="Door">
<xsl:element name="Door">
  <xsl:attribute name="color">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../@gender = 'Boy' ">Red</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="../@gender = 'Girl' ">Green</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

You should do the same for 'Key' template (or better reuse the 'choose' code by extracting it into separate [named template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5280.html)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: First thanks for you replay but this solution doesn´t work. My output is now "<Door color="Red"/>" but I want this "<Door color="Red">Lamborghini</Door>

Comment: I now got it! I just added <xsl:apply-templates/> in front of the </xsl:element> :)